# Will Ataxite be the type of nickel-iron sought for asteroid mining?

Tags: asteroid, mining, meteorites, minerals

The high value metals in meteorites and asteroids - mostly Platinum Group Metals - appear associated with the nickel content ([The Occurrence of Platinum in Meteorites, F. G. Hawley,1939](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1945-5100.1939.tb00235.x)), ie the highest PGM content is found within the high nickel content meteorites. The meteorite mineral [Taenite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taenite) has the highest nickel content - 20% - 65%. But does Taenite occur *on it's own, as a distinct material*? Or is it *only* found as crystals and bands within lower nickel content materials?

[Ataxite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ataxite) is a high Taenite content form of meteorite nickel-iron, with a nickel content between about 15 - 30%. If Taenite does not appear on it's own will Ataxite be the preferred type of asteroid metal for mining potential?